# Optimal way to serve data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a application in which I must serve videos to a user. If the user has already voted that video it should no longer be served.

Currently I am storing in a table

ID, video_id, user, mark

The following query is executed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT video_id,user,ID 
FROM votes 
WHERE ID > {$_POST['normal_index']} 
AND video_id 
NOT IN (SELECT video_id FROM votes WHERE user = '{$_POST['user_id']}')
LIMIT {$_POST['normal_count']}"
```

This approach is slow, how can I speed up things? Should I hold only an entry for a video_id, but how can I determine if that video was voted or not?

Comment: That's [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.

Comment: @doublesharp I've sanitzed the parameters properly before. thanks for the tip

Comment: To optimized the query 1. Use prepared statement to avoid sql injection.  2. Check ID and video_id is indexed in the table. 3. After that we can talk about making the query better.

Comment: Which indexes did you set up?

Comment: Maybe put `EXPLAIN` before your query and add results here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT video_id,user,ID 
FROM votes 
WHERE ID > {$_POST['normal_index']} AND 
user <> '{$_POST['user_id']}' 
LIMIT {$_POST['normal_count']}
```

Comment: Although, this is still vulnerable to SQL Injection as stated by @doublesharp.

Comment: I give solution for speed up not for injection

Comment: My previous comment was for anyone else's reference that may not be aware.

Comment: @Sadikhasan thanks for your help but won't already voted videos appear in this query ?

Comment: You mentioned above your query is perfect for you

Comment: Can i help further what you want?

Comment: In original query he selects only videos which user was not voting previously. You select videos which are not owned by user, but using your query user can see videos he already voted for.